# How to deploy file war in apache tomcat server and Glassfish server with netbeans?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deploy a Java Web Application (.war) on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217693/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-war-on-tomcat)

I have built a web application with Netbeans and Java Server Faces into a `*.war` file and now I want to deploy it on a different computer, but I don't know how to do that.

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you even try to google for this? Also look through SO before asking such a basic question, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119678/how-can-i-deploy-war-in-tomcat-6

Answer (score 0):

In your different computer there should be a Web Server that can be Apache Tomcat. Just copy your .war file and go to webapps folder of that Apache Tomcat Installation Folder and paste it. Now, you can browse it through web browser.