# Integration of custom Java web app in SAP BusinessObjects BI 4.0

Tags: java, business-objects

Can anyone represent step by step guideline of custom Java web app integration in SAP BusinessObjects BI 4.0 (using BI Tomcat6). I could not find any solution in the internet, pitifully. In my custom app, for example, I would like to to get SAP users and show it throughout the .jsp file. Any advice?

In advance, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to add custom code into the existing packaged WARs or are you writing your own WAR that can stand alone?

Comment: I am writing my own WAR that should deployed with SAP WARs. Perphaps, I am choosing wrong way in implementation of my task. Its content is to automate entrance in BOE in case if user is present in my system (LDAP), and accordingly create user at BOE side.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom application to talk and interact with SAP BOE is overall quite simple.  All of the libraries that you need are available in <BO Install Dir>\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java\lib.  No you don't need all 323 jars, but from my personal usage there are at least 70 of jars that are required and you may not need the same set as I do depending on which features you are using.  So now you have the entire SDK that you can work with BOE via and is all that SAP's base WARs use.

Basics of your code will include:

```
// Get logged in
ISessionMgr sessionManager = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = sessionManager.logon(user, pass, cms, authType);

// Get the IInfoStore to look at the CMS database
IInfoStore infoStore = (IInfoStore) enterpriseSession.getService("InfoStore");
IInfoObjects infoObjects = infoStore.query("select * from CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_NAME='FRED'");
// do things with the results here

// Log off the session
enterpriseSession.logoff();
```

For more information it would be best to go read the SDK documents from SAP.  This will give you better information on interacting with the IInfoStore.  The calls to SAP BOE can be done through a standard Java Application or Java EE application though so as long as you aren't trying to integrate your changes directly into the BI LaunchPad or CMC it should be pretty simple.

For deployment under the SAP provided Tomcat, I recommend reading the following StackOverflow: [How can I deploy war in Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119678/how-can-i-deploy-war-in-tomcat-6)

Comment: U said it completely easy to integrate my own app to BOE, but can U provide how to deploy my app in their Tomcat, because in this stage I have a problem - at the end I wish that my app should start with BOE WARs when their Tomcat starts.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you stated *(…) to automate entrance in BOE in case if user is present in my system (LDAP), and accordingly create user at BOE side*.

If what you want to do is integrate an LDAP system with your BusinessObjects environment, then you can do so without having to use the SDK. Have a look at the administrator guide for BI4 (available at [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com)). LDAP is one of the available third-party security plugins and will allow you retrieve users from an existing LDAP server.

The only limitation with the LDAP integration is that SSO (single sign-on) is not supported unless you have e.g. SiteMinder at your disposal. If SSO is what you need, you could combine LDAP with Trusted Authentication. Again, have a look at the administrator guide to see what options are available regarding integration of external authentication providers.